# Ambiguous mapping error : Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, mapping

When i deploy my code I get error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'programController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.quizapp.beans.controller.panal.ProgramController.editProgram(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
to {[],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'programController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.quizapp.beans.controller.panal.ProgramController.setupProgram(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,org.springframework.ui.Model) mapped.
```

Below is my programController class

```
    @Controller
    public class ProgramController {

    @RequestMapping(name = "/editProgram", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editProgram(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        if (request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER) != null) {
            ProgramEntity program = new ProgramEntity();
            if (request.getParameter("id") == null) {// create
                program.setType("create");
            } else {// edit
                program.setType("edit");
                program.setCode(request.getParameter("id"));

            }
            request.setAttribute("programBean", program);
            return "editProgram";

        } else {
            return "redirect:/login";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(name = "/program", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupProgram(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        if (session.getAttribute(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER) != null) {
            model.addAttribute("programBean", new ProgramEntity());
            // if (request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER) != null) {
            // request.setAttribute("programBean", new ProgramEntity());
            return "viewProgram";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/login";
        }
    }
}
```

When i make the method editProgram as POST then it deploy perfectly.
Why is there problem with adding two GET method.
There are many similar questions available on StackOverflow but i couldn't find right answer.

Comment: You should give the value parameter in @RequestMapping annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are specifying different [`names`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#name--) of `RequestMapping` and not [`values`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value--). Currently, `value` of both the methods are same (`""` - empty) which is not allowed. Your URL part of request mapping should be specified in `value` and not `name` attribute of [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).

Comment: You saved the day, Thanku very much. Such a silly mistake. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
@Controller
public class ProgramController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/editProgram", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editProgram(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER) != null) {
        ProgramEntity program = new ProgramEntity();
        if (request.getParameter("id") == null) {// create
            program.setType("create");
        } else {// edit
            program.setType("edit");
            program.setCode(request.getParameter("id"));

        }
        request.setAttribute("programBean", program);
        return "editProgram";

    } else {
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value= "/program", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupProgram(HttpSession session, Model model) {
    if (session.getAttribute(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER) != null) {
        model.addAttribute("programBean", new ProgramEntity());
        // if (request.getSession().getAttribute(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER) != null) {
        // request.setAttribute("programBean", new ProgramEntity());
        return "viewProgram";
    } else {
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
}
```